# Java: Exception in thread main java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, red5

I am trying to get the Red5 Flash Media Server working on my computer. I have installed it, but when I run the server I get this error:-

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/red5/server/Bootstrap
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.red5.server.Bootstrap
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:334)
  Could not find the main class: org.red5.server.Bootstrap. Program will exit.
```

I came across this link where someone had the same issue:
http://trac.red5.org/ticket/762

It looks like they ran the following command:

```
export CLASSPATH=3D$RED5_HOME/lib/slf4j-api-1.5.10.jar:$RED5_HOME/lib/logback-   core-0.9.18.jar:$RED5_HOME/lib/logback-classic-0.9.18.jar
```

I have red5 installed in /usr/share/red5, so I ran this:

```
export CLASSPATH=3D$/usr/share/red5/lib/slf4j-api-1.5.10.jar:$/usr/share/red5/lib/logback-core-0.9.18.jar:$/usr/share/red5/lib/logback-classic-0.9.18.jar
```

Yet despite all this I am still seeing the same error message.

Answer (score 7):

I used to have the same problem like `"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.red5.server.Bootstrap"` after  I builded a new red5 server from the trunk to 'dist' directory

just point RED5_HOME environment variable  to that `"dist"` location.

Answer (score 2):

The correct class path is:

```
export CLASSPATH=/usr/share/red5/lib/slf4j-api-1.5.10.jar:/usr/share/red5/lib/logback-core-0.9.18.jar:/usr/share/red5/lib/logback-classic-0.9.18.jar
```

Notice:

- No 3D after `=` sign
- No `$` before `/usr` anywhere

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure your red5.sh has the correct permissions:

```
chmod 755 red5.sh
```

The java AccessController is failing, thus the class is not being found.

Answer (score 1):

You did not build it from source after svn checkout. Just type ant after checkout :).

Answer (score 0):

This might be incorrect:

```
export CLASSPATH=3D$/usr/share/red5/lib/slf4j-api-1.5.10.jar:$/usr/share/red5/lib/logback-core-0.9.18.jar:$/usr/share/red5/lib/logback-classic-0.9.18.jar
```

I think it should be:

```
export CLASSPATH=/usr/share/red5/lib/slf4j-api-1.5.10.jar:/usr/share/red5/lib/logback-core-0.9.18.jar:/usr/share/red5/lib/logback-classic-0.9.18.jar
```

If that doesn't work, then the server is ignoring the CLASSPATH environment variable.  Java EE app servers don't use it.  Which server software are you using as the listener?

Comment: I didn't have any luck changing that command.  The error message remains.  I am using sun-java6-jdk according to this tutorial, http://builddocs.com/streaming_media/installing-red5-0-8-on-ubuntu-9-04/.

Answer (score 0):

The red5 bootstrap class is in the boot.jar and this is the only jar that needs to be on the classpath when starting red5.